# Fast Enumeration in parse

Tags: json, parsing, ios6, enumeration

I'm new to iOS and I'm trying to parse out JSON data. Nothing will log from inside of the enumeration,  though vehicleActivity logs "vehicle (null).I am interested in logging the "LineRef" data. I'm assuming it is in NSString,  but I tried with id object and still nothing.

```
NSDictionary *jsonParse = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:webData options:0 error:nil];
NSArray * vehicleActivity = [jsonParse objectForKey:@"VechicleActivity"];
NSLog(@"vehicle %@",vehicleActivity);

for (NSDictionary *dictionary in vehicleActivity ) {
    NSDictionary *monitoredVehJourney = [dictionary objectForKey:@"MonitoredVehicleJourney"];
    NSString *line = [monitoredVehJourney objectForKey:@"LineRef"];
    NSLog(@"Line # %@",line);
```

Here is the JSON through a viewer

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

> though vehicleActivity logs "vehicle (null)"

That's why. If `vehicleActivity` is `NULL` (i. e., `nil`), then the fast enumeration wouldn't even begin.

Furthermore, you seem not to have read the documentation of the `NSDictionary` class. It iterates through keys, not values. So your for loop should be

```
for (NSString *key in vehicleActivity ) {
    NSDictionary *dictionary = [vehicleActivity objectForKey:key];
    // etc.
}
```

instead.

Furthermore, I believe you have a typo in your code regarding the key `VehicleActivity`. You wrote it as `VechicleActivity`.